# zip a directory except all file and folders with a specific name

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I know that I can do

```
zip -r archive.zip ./mydir -x ./mydir/dir_x/* ./mydir/dir_y/dir_z/dir_x/*
```

to exclude those two folders, but how can I exclude all directories and files by name and not by path?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-x` option of `zip` is for filtering out file**names**, you can't use it for excluding a directory.

A workaround is to list all the filepaths that you want to put in your `zip` archive; here's how you can do it with GNU/BSD `find`:

```bash
find mydir ! -type d ! -path '*/dir_x/*' |
zip archive.zip -@
```